# Determine the asymptotic runtime of an algorithm using vectors, sets, or lists

Tags: c++, list, vector, complexity-theory, deque

I'm having trouble finding the asymptotic runtime with some C++ code. If you're just changing the data structure -- between vectors, sets, and lists, how would that change the asymptomatic runtime?

When I tried to find it I got O(n^3) for all of them, but I know that's not true since they vary in execution speeds. For example, using lists yields a much faster speed than vector. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated! Just to be clear, to change the code, I just switched out vector, to list, and then to deque.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    
using namespace std;
template <typename T>

long returnSum(T datatype, int NN)
{
    datatype.clear();
    for (int ii=0; ii<NN; ii++)
        datatype.insert(datatype.begin(), ii);
    long sum=0;
    typename T::reverse_iterator iter=datatype.rbegin();
    for (; iter!=datatype.rend(); iter++)
        sum += *iter;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 1000;
    int myArray[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)  //make an array with designated values
        myArray[i] = i;
  //convert array to vector
    std::vector<int> Vec (myArray, myArray+sizeof(myArray)/ sizeof (int) );
    long test = returnSum(Vec, SIZE);
    cout << "Sum is: " << test << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: C++ vector's don't handle repeated insertion at the head very efficiently. Each insert moves all the existing elements along by one. Are you aware of this feature?

Comment: Wonderful, the "asymptomatic runtime" made my day. It's like chlamydia for men.

Comment: asymptotic complexitiy is a theoretical concept while execution speed is something very real that you can measure more easily. It can well be that an algorithm A has O(n) and some other B has O(n^2) but when you measure runtime, B can be faster than A. Asymptotic complexity only tells you what happens when the size of the input goes to infinity

Comment: also the big O notation only cares about the leading term (because thats all what matters if n goes to infinity). Thus, in general O(n^3) is not the same as O(n^3), unless n really goes to infinity ;)

Comment: @Jon Chesterfield, yes I am aware that vectors are not very efficient at repeated insertion since it had the longest runtime. However, I wasn't aware that all the existing elements had to be moved along by one. Thanks for telling me

Comment: @KerrekSB, that comment just made my day

Comment: Insert at the end of the vector would be amortised constant time. I think the start pointer could actually be some distance into oversized contiguous memory, allowing some O(1) inserts at the head, without violating the spec - but don't know of any implementation that does so and am not wholly confident this would be permitted